# Dart encapsulated list (just for observing values)

Tags: flutter, dart, encapsulation

I have the following lists

```
List<ProductVariation> _productVariations = []; avoid null pointer exceptions
List<ProductVariation> get productVariations => _productVariations;
```

The main goal for adding `List<ProductVariation> get productVariations => _productVariations;` was to avoid `_productVariations` to be modified, however, I'm able to add, delete or do any operations inside the list, how can I prevent `productVariations` to be modified when accessed from another file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative solution is to use `UnmodifiableListView` from `dart:collection` which can be a lot more efficient since you are not making a new copy of the list but are instead just serving a protected view of your `List`:

```
import 'dart:collection';

class A {
  final List<int> _data = [1, 2, 3];
  UnmodifiableListView<int> get data => UnmodifiableListView(_data);
}

void main() {
  final a = A();
  print(a.data); // [1, 2, 3]
  a.data.add(5); // Unhandled exception: Unsupported operation: Cannot add to an unmodifiable list
}
```

A downside of this solution is that `UnmodifiableListView` is a normal `List` seen from the analyzers point of view so you will not get any statically errors from doing this. But you will get an exception on runtime if you try modify the list itself. For making it more clear for the developer I think it is nice to specify that the returned type is `UnmodifiableListView` even if you could just write `List` instead.

Another point is that this solution (or the one suggested by Jigar Patel) does not prevents you from modifying the objects itself in the list if the objects are not immutable. So if you also want to prevent these changes you need to make deep copies of the objects.

Comment: Another downside I noticed when attempting swapping UnmodifiableListView in place of Lists is that it'll also ruin any null checks since it's a wrapper and not the actual list itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the getter return a copy of the list like this.

```
List<ProductVariation> get productVariations => [..._productVariations];
```

Or

```
List<ProductVariation> get productVariations => _productVariations.toList();
```